# Python: prevent %s substitution on a string

Tags: python

Is there a way to mark a string such that it will not trigger python's % string substitution?

In particular, I'm attempting to download a file whose name includes a % using the python `sftp` module. The sftp module attempts to log the name of the file using the logging module:

```
self.logger.log(level, msg, *args)
```

and `logging` complains about string formatting because of the % signs:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

So: since I don't control the filename nor the sftp module, can I mark the filename as not participating in string substitution?

Comment: You should report that as a bug to sftp: They should do proper escaping self.logger.log(level, "%s" % msg, *args)

Comment: Agreed, I just filed the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mystring.replace('%', '%%')` might suit your needs. `%%` escapes a `%`.

Comment: Strangely enough that works - I'd assumed escaping the % would cause the sftp download to fail to find the file (since its name no longer matches the remote file name), but apparently it works fine. Should've tried it instead of assuming I guess.